# Why is basename in this shell script necessary?

Tags: shell, directory, move, basename

I found this shell script(`$1`,`$2` are directories):

```
mv "$2" "$1"  ||  exit               # Make $2 a subdirectory of $1
cd "$1/$(basename "$2")"  ||  exit   # Change directories for simplicity
for f in *; do
    mv "$f" "${f%.*}.txt"            # Add or change the extension
done
```

it moves the second directory in the first one (so the second directory becomes a subdirectory of the first one) and all the files from the second directory will have a ".txt" extension. I can't figure out why `cd "$1/$2"` won't work doesn't basename strip the filename from a given directory? Could someone explain how this part:
`cd "$1/$(basename "$2")"` works? Also $2 needs to be in  separate quotes(`"$2"`) because of basename?

Comment: Suppose the script is invoked with arguments `/full/path/to/1 /full/path/to/2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `basename` removes the leading directory information. Assume that the sript is called with arguments like this:

```
$$> script usr/local/foo usr/local/bar
```

Now the `$2` is equal to `usr/local/bar`.

If you only do `cd $1/$2`, the command will look like this:

```
cd usr/local/foo/usr/local/bar
```

But in reality, it should be

```
cd usr/local/foo/bar
```

It is removing this directory prefix from `usr/local/bar` is whhat is done by `basename`.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/basename-command-in-linux-with-examples/

Comment: and if I would call the script  like this :  script directory1 directory2(without the path just simply the directory name) than  cd $1/$2 would work right?

Answer (score 0):

> Also $2 needs to be in separate quotes("$2") because of basename?

Yes, there's the outer set of expansions `"$1/$(...)"`, and the inner expansion `"$2"` that both need to be quoted to prevent issues with [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) which would otherwise break the command if `$2` contained whitespace (or shell glob characters).

See e.g. [Quoting within $(command substitution) in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118433/170373) on unix.SE for the details.

(Actually that should be `cd -- "$1/$(basename -- "$2")"` to guard against filenames/paths starting with `-`, too.)

Comment: @ikkachiu and why is % after f necessary I know that .* repeats 0 or an many times as possible but what does %?

Comment: @newhere http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073?action=show&redirect=ParameterExpansion